# safest method to upgrade Rails app from 3.0.3 to 3.0.XX (probably 3.0.17)? pitfalls?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a somewhat older Rails app (3.0.3) we're working on. At the moment we don't have time to upgrade it to 3.1 or 3.2.

But is a Rails 3.0.3 -> Rails 3.0.17 update safe and automatic? I'm assuming with minor versions, there's NO code changes in our app that will be imposed?

Is there any reason to do it step-wise, such as if going from 3.0 to 3.2 I've read going to 3.1 first is a good idea. And if so, which steps? (Eg something like 3.0.3 -> 3.0.5 -> 3.0.10 -> 3.0.17)

Comment: The one thing that always gets me in point-releases is changes in the config files. You can create a new rails 3.0.x project, diff the rails files of import, and you'll know. Oh and run your tests of course :)

Comment: I wouldn't take the time to go stepwise FWIW -- all or nothing seems to be the simplest. For bigger releases, that *can* make sense (3.0 => 3.1 => 3.2) but for 3.0.x => 3.0.y, not worth it.

Comment: great suggestion to create a new project to see the default config files thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, even better yet, create a rails project using 3.03 and then upgrade to 3.17 (or whatever) and check out git diff or gitk on your machine.  It will show you exactly what core files changed.  That'll make upgrading WAY easier.

Also, do yourself a favor and try upgrading in a git branch so you can revert easily if need be.